# System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Unauthenticated senders not allowed

Tags: smtp, sendgrid

So I'm using Sendgrid for an email form on a website.
When the form is submitted I get this error:

[image]

My smtp setting in the config file are like this:

[image]

I know it looks like the username or password is incorrect because it sais Unauthenticated senders not allowed, but I have other web sites using the same smtp settings on the same server, that work fine.

Also I tested the connection using this method:

[image]

And I get Authentication successful, with the same username and password provided.

What could be causing this error?